# Android: binding of RecyclerView

Tags: android, data-binding, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

I've made a simple binding in RecyclerView.

I created ViewHolder like this:

```
class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    ItemBinding binding;

    public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.bind(itemView);
    }
}
```

Binding is done like this

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    MyItem item= items.get(position);
    // bind model with data
    holder.binding.setItem(item);
}
```

I read [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDatabinding/article.html) tutorial and see that ViewHolder is like this:

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    private final ViewDataBinding binding;

    public MyViewHolder(ViewDataBinding binding) {
        super(binding.getRoot());
        this.binding = binding;
    }
    public void bind(Object obj) {
        binding.setVariable(BR.obj,obj);
        binding.executePendingBindings();
    }
}
```

And Adapter is

```
 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
     final TemperatureData temperatureData = data.get(position);
     holder.bind(temperatureData);
 }
```

My question is why do we need `public void bind(Object obj)` method if it works without it?

I have less code and it works but being new to Android I'm scared to miss something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method ensures setters for any class will be generated.

In most cases though, it is not necesssary.

So yes, you can delete this method - worst thing that can happen here is that you add a class to your app for which the setter wouldn't generate (at which point you know where to look for a solution)

[More info here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ViewDataBinding.html#setVariable(int,%20java.lang.Object))